# Multiple login urls in Shiro

Tags: url, shiro

I am trying to configure apache shiro to authenticate our application based on apache click.
We have two different login urls for two types of users in the same application

1) For District users : districtlogin.jsp
2) For State Users : statelogin.jsp

How can i specify these 2 urls in the shiro.ini file

Now only one url is working at a time .

I used the below methods

shiro.loginUrl = /statelogin.jsp
shiro.loginUrl = /districtlogin.jsp

Thankyou

Comment: Why two different login pages?  Also, if a user hits a page that requires login, shiro will redirect them to the login page.  How should it decide which page to go to?

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I need 2 different login URLs because it will be accessed from 2 target, web client and a mobile client (via RESTful).
So I cannot apply the same login action at controller for both of them (because the input and output are absolutely different), but reuse the service methods from 2 actions.
Do we have any way to let Shiro knows that there are 2 available valid login URLs?